# Rerun a request after fixing some problem with express.js

Tags: express

My express.js application interfaces with an internal application that once in a while changes its exposed connection port.

If a request fails, next() will call an error middleware function that checks the internal application's port and updates it if needed.

At this point I would like to automatically reprocess the request from the initial route, i.e. restarting the middleware stack from the beginning.

How can I do that? I only know how to go down the middleware stack but not how to go back up.

I could send a 503 http code to the browser to have it retry the request but it feels silly not to reprocess it directly on the server.

EDIT

Attaching some code to make it clearer:

```
function getInternalPort() {
    ... read from file current port of internal application server...
}

let port = getInternalPort()

app.get('...a route...', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await functionThatUsesPort()
        res.json(result)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}

const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
    if (error.code == 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        port = getInternalPort()

        ??? CODE TO REPROCESS THE REQUEST ???

    } else {
          res.json(null);
          console.log(err);
    }
}

app.use(errorHandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any Express features that allows you to restart routing over again.

You can, however just create your own wrapper function that will do one retry after resetting the port and use that in whichever request handlers you want retry with.  This way, you can just handle the retry yourself and not be asking Express to do it for you:

```
function getInternalPort() {
    ... read from file current port of internal application server...
}

async function retryUponPortError(fn, next, ...args) {
    try {
        const result = await fn(...args);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            port = getInternalPort()
            try {
                const result = await fn(...args);
                return result;
            } catch(error) {
                next(error);
            }
        } else {
            next(error);
        }
    }
}

let port = getInternalPort()

app.get('/someroute', async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = await retryUponPortError(functionThatUsesPort, next, arg1, arg2);
    res.json(result);
}

const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
    res.json(null);
    console.log(err);
}

app.use(errorHandler)
```

Note, this code also saves you from having to do the `try/catch` in your own request handler as that is done in the `retryUponPortError()` wrapper.

Note, `arg1` and `arg2` are whatever arguments you might want to pass to your `functionThatUsesPort()` call.  You can have zero arguments or as many as you want.  Whichever ones you pass after the `next` argument to `retryUponPortError()` will be passed to your function.

Comment: I have been studying Express documentation and couldn't find any way to have Express do it either. I like your solution, it keeps the code succinct.

Answer (score -1):

You can re-route the request using `next('route')`. So, in the `errorHandler` function, just put `next('..a route')` and it will restart the chain.

Comment: I have different routes that would all pass control to errorHandler, how can I pass to next the route that called errorHandler?

Comment: Append the route you want to restart the chain from in the req object. Do something like `req.restarterRoute = "/route-you-want"`. Then, on errorHandler, do `next(req.restarterRoute)`.

Comment: Or you could just pass the initial route with `next(req.path)`

Comment: I am using next(req.path) and what happens is this:

(1) the console prints the correct req.path

(2) the browser returns html with a title tag of "Error" and a body tag with inside <pre>...the req.path...</pre>

(3) If I refresh the browser then I get the correct response

Comment: OK, I think that if you call next('...whatever...') express.js consider ...whatever... an error, it does not unfortunately consider it a route to reprocess

Comment: Can you point to any Express documentation that says you can do `next('/somepath')` and that it will start rerouting again from the top?  I can't find it anywhere in the doc and have never heard of this.  As best I know `next('route')` is a very special case with that particular `'route'` string that just tells it to skip further routing in THIS particular router.

Comment: FYI, relevant Express code for `next()` is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L177).  I see a specific check for the words `'route'` and `'router'` and otherwise, it seems like the argument is treated as an error condition.  The code is a bit cryptic so I'm happy to have someone point out how it could do what this answer proposes, but I don't see it.